# Looking to match entries in a dataset to a list using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large dataset made up of lists with multiple entries. I want to change this instead of column of entries, with the lists they appear in in the adjacent cells.

For example, the datasets look like this:

```
1          2         3
Alpha      Alpha     Beta
Delta      Beta      Echo
Echo       Echo      Golf
Golf       Golf      Hotel
```

But I want to make something that looks like this:

```
 Alpha 1 2 
 Beta  2 3
 Delta 1 
 Echo  1 2 3
 Golf  1 2 3
```

Right now, I'm thinking of writing a very elaborate If... Do While loop instructing excel to cut and paste the entries a certain way if the variables (alpha, beta, etc) are equal. However, I imagine there must be an easier way. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should atleast try something by yourself first and then ask for help if stuck. Anyway what I can advice is to you copy everything from the three columns into one separate columns and remove the duplicates and then take each string one by one from that column and test for match in any column using simple if else and then output the result in preferred format hope that helps.

Comment: Sure, I'm trying a few things out myself. I just want to see if there is a totally different approach I'm not considering. Your answer is exactly the type I'm looking for. I'll try it out. Thanks.